# What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Which style is preferred?
Is there a good reason for one vs. the other?

Thanks in advance!

```
1) cmds.each do |cmd|
   end

2) cmds.each { |cmd|
   }
```

Example code:

```
cmds = [ "create", "update", "list", "help" ]

# Block style one
#
cmds.each do |cmd|
  puts "loop1, cmd: #{cmd}"
end

# Block style two
#
cmds.each { |cmd|
  puts "loop2, cmd: #{cmd}"
}
```

Comment: there is no difference, the do/end one is just nicer. also i corrected your question

Comment: Thanks Iraimbilanja, your changes make sense to me.

Comment: @Iraimbilanja: There is a difference, as described in the answers.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37638767/405017

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The rails team and many other rubyists [prefer](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/CodingStandards) to use curly braces for one line blocks and `do...end` for multi-line ones.

The only functional difference between the two is that the precedence of a `do...end` block is lower than that of a `{...}` block.

Comment: They are the same thing though.  So when using braces, you would write it on one line like: `cmds.each { |cmd| puts "loop2, cmd: #{cmd}" }`

Answer (score 23):

According to [the "Pickaxe" book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby) (I'm looking at the 2nd edition here), Gordon's correct: the only difference is precedence:

p.356 (my italics) :

> Braces have a high precedence; `do`
>   has a low precedence. If the method
>   invocation has parameters that are not
>   enclosed in parentheses, the *brace
>   form of a block will bind to the last
>   parameter, not to the overall
>   invocation*. The `do` form will *bind
>   to the invocation*.

See also p.168 for an example.

Answer (score 13):

The two forms are equivalent.

The recommended style is to use the braces for one line blocks and use the "do"-"end" for multiline blocks.

**Edit:** [Austin Ziegler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36378/austin-ziegler/) pointed out (in the comment below) that the two forms have difference precedence levels: Curly braces have higher precedence. Therefore, when calling a method without parenthesis a block enclosed in {} will bind to the last argument instead of the calling method.

The following example was suggested by Austin:

```
def foo
    yield
end

puts foo { "hello" }

puts foo do
    "hello"
end
```

The first "puts" prints "hello": foo gets called returning "hello" which is the argument to puts.

The second bails with an error:

```
in `foo': no block given
```

Since in this case the do-end block binds to the puts method.

Thanks again to Austin for clearing this up.

Comment: No, they're not.

    def foo
      yield
    end

    puts foo { "hello" }
    puts foo do; "hello"; end

The latter will throw an exception. The former will not (and it will print "hello"). { } binds to #foo; do/end binds to #puts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have edited the answer giving you the credit. You should have really added your own answer so that the original poster could mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

Gordon's answer is "the Ruby Way," and although it is a common practice to put one line in braces, it is not required.

Also note the ease with which one can act on the resulting value:

```
cmds.each do |cmd| cmd.upcase! end.sort

# Now, cmds = ["CREATE", "HELP", "LIST", "UPDATE"]
```

Although you might already see how `{}` is more readable here, and therefore preferred if anyone else is going to see your code:

```
cmds.each { |cmd| cmd.upcase! }.sort
```

Comment: zandev, Thanks for the extra tip on 'end.sort'

Answer (score 3):

Most often, style 1 is used for multiple-line blocks and style 2 is used for one-liners.

The `do…end` syntax closely resembles other Ruby control structures (if, def, class), so using that for blocks keeps the appearance of your code consistent and clear. But it doesn't work well for one-liners, which is why the brackets version is preferred there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it really matters - it's just an aesthetic personal choice. Some people prefer to use the `do...end` version when the block needs multiple lines and the `{...}` version when its all on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Conventionally, using `{}` is reserved for single-line blocks, while `do...end` is for multi-line blocks.

Because of how `{}` are not used in Ruby as often as in other languages like C++ or Javascript, using `do...end` when given the chance instead of `{}` can help make your code more readable for other Rubyists.

Note that `{}` has precedence over `do...end`.