# Rails: named_scope, lambda and blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

I thought the following two were equivalent:

```
named_scope :admin, lambda { |company_id| {:conditions => ['company_id = ?', company_id]} }

named_scope :admin, lambda do |company_id| 
  {:conditions => ['company_id = ?', company_id]}
end
```

but Ruby is complaining:

```
ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you want either a lambda or a block, not both. So in the second case just get rid of the lambda and pass in a block. That should do the same as the first.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

it's a parser problem. try this

```
named_scope :admin, (lambda do |company_id| 
  {:conditions => ['company_id = ?', company_id]}
end)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's 'a parser problem', but your code should fix it.

Comment: khelll: yeah, 'problem' is a bit of a misstatement, i'll admit. it's a matter of the lower precedence of do...end, as mike woodhouse explains.

Answer (score 19):

I think the problem may be related to the difference in precedence between `{...}` and `do...end`

There's some SO discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533008/what-is-the-difference-or-value-of-these-block-coding-styles-in-ruby)

I think assigning a lambda to a variable (which would be a Proc) *could* be done with a `do 
... end`:

```
my_proc = lambda do 
  puts "did it"
end
my_proc.call #=> did it
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're on ruby 1.9 or later <sup>1</sup>, you can use the lambda literal (arrow syntax), which has high enough precedence to prevent the method call from "stealing" the block from the lambda.

```
named_scope :admin, ->(company_id) do 
  {:conditions => ['company_id = ?', company_id]}
end
```

---

<sup>1 The first stable Ruby 1.9.1 release was 2009-01-30.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

It's something related to precedence as I can tell

```
1.upto 3 do # No parentheses, block delimited with do/end
  |x| puts x 
end

1.upto 3 {|x| puts x } # Syntax Error: trying to pass a block to 3!
```