# How can I write the most efficient scope for asking only those parent objects which have some certain child objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I have:

```
class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores
end
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_disability_and_score,
        lambda { |disability, score|
          where('total_score >= ? AND name = ?', score, disability)
        }
end
```

The `scores` table has a `total_score` field and a `name` field.

How can i write a `scope` to ask for only those `evaluations` which have a `Score` with name 'vision' and `total_score` of 2 and they have another `Score` with name 'hearing' and `total_score` of 3. 
And how can all this be generalized to ask for those evaluations which have n scores with my parameters?

In raw sql it would be like:

```
I managed to do it in raw sql:

sql = %q-SELECT "evaluations".*
FROM "evaluations"
INNER JOIN "scores" AS s1 ON "s1"."evaluation_id" = "evaluations"."id"
INNER JOIN "target_disabilities" AS t1 ON "t1"."id" = "s1"."target_disability_id"
INNER JOIN "scores" AS s2 ON "s2"."evaluation_id" = "evaluations"."id"
INNER JOIN "target_disabilities" AS t2 ON "t2"."id" = "s2"."target_disability_id"
WHERE "t1"."name" = 'vision' AND (s1.total_score >= 1)
      AND "t2"."name" = 'hearing' AND (s2.total_score >= 2)-
```

Here the point is to repeat this:

```
INNER JOIN "scores" AS s1 ON "s1"."evaluation_id" = "evaluations"."id"
```

and this (by replacing s1 to s2 and s3 and so forth):

```
WHERE (s1.total_score >= 1)
```

But it should be a rails way of doing this... :) Hopefully

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scope :by_scores, lambda do |params|
    if params.is_a? Hash
      query = joins(:scores)
      params.each_pair do |name, score|
        query = query.where( 'scores.total_score >= ? AND scores.name = ?', score, name)
      end
      query
    end
 end
```

Then call like this:

```
Evaluation.by_scores 'vision' => 2, 'hearing' => 3
```

Comment: Could you fix the typo (Hahs -> Hash), please? I can't do this because edits must be at least 6 characters.

Comment: How can I change the query to check if the total score is greater than my score?

Comment: That code just doubles the WHERE statements... It would generate this sql, which is not what I need:

    SELECT "evaluations".* FROM "evaluations" INNER JOIN "scores" ON "scores"."evaluation_id" = "evaluations"."id" INNER JOIN "target_disabilities" ON "target_disabilities"."id" = "scores"."target_disability_id" WHERE "target_disabilities"."name" = 'vision' AND "target_disabilities"."name" = 'hearing' AND (scores.total_score >= 1) AND (scores.total_score >= 2)

Comment: @Boti, another approach is not use N joins, but use group by. For example, replace `AND` into your pairs and then group by `evaluations.id` and filter by pairs count. Please, response if you wish an example with `meta_where` or `squeel`.

Comment: Mark: It was a great idea. It is much more simpler to put together the query by grouping. Let me show you:
    sql = %q-select evaluation_id FROM (SELECT evaluation_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM "scores" INNER JOIN "target_disabilities" AS t1 ON "t1"."id" = "scores"."target_disability_id" 
    WHERE ('t1'.'name' = 'vision' AND (scores.total_score >= 1)) 
    OR ('t1'.'name' ='hearing' AND (scores.total_score >= 2)) GROUP BY evaluation_id)
WHERE count = 2-

Comment: Another observation: the lambda do |params|... will trigger a parser error. It should be written like scope :by_scores, (lambda do |params|...).
See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476678/rails-named-scope-lambda-and-blocks

Comment: After doing some research... It seems to me that ActiveRecord::Relation doesn't support the 'OR' in 'WHERE'-s. Or does it? 
It can be done easily with squeel.

Comment: Rails 3 has build in Areal: [see SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query)