# How do I build a scope that will pass the first relationship back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so i have users and company and there a a join table on a many to many relationship

SO i can do

```
@user.companies
```

Can i do a scope that passes back the first company

i tied this in the user model

```
 scope :first_company, includes(:companies_users).where(:user_id => self.id).first
```

and this fails....any suggestions

Update

I have this that will work also but i was wondering if there was a equivalent scope

```
 def company
   self.companies.first
 end
```

Comment: `User` already has the method `first`. Use another name for your scope.

Comment: sorry that was just an example...changing

Comment: Scope works on the whole model. Like `User.admins`. You're trying to make some "scope" on the `@user`, which obviously makes no sense: scope limits results, what can you limit on the `@user`? So, you're right when you create method, which is called on a particular user rather than on all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your scope as a lambda as the context of self in a scope would be the class not the instance.

see this SO article for how to do that.

[Ruby Lambda and Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476678/rails-named-scope-lambda-and-blocks)