# Scope but error message ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I am tring to create a scope which find out all contacts with 0 address. `Got error message ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block` when running command 'Contact.noaddress' in rails c.

Here is my contact model including scope:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :firstname, :lastname, :mobilephone, :fullname
  has_many :addresses
  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname


   scope :noaddressed, lambda do |addresses|
    joins(:addresses).where('addresses.created_at.empty?', true)
   end
end
```

and here's address model

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :country, :postalcode, :region, :street
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

Could somebody help me please?

Answer (score 30):

It sounds like a (precedence issue?) referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476678/rails-named-scope-lambda-and-blocks).

If you change the scope to:

```
scope :noaddresses, (lambda do
  joins(:addresses).where('addresses.created_at is null')
end)
```

or

```
scope :noaddresses, lambda { joins(:addresses).where('addresses.created_at is null') }
```

Also, I don't see where you're using the block argument `|addresses|`. Did you forget to use it? Otherwise, you can remove it and its surrounding pipes.

Updated: I removed the `|addresses|` argument and updated the query to be valid SQL syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. but got error 'ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)' even i used named_scope

Comment: The addresses argument needs to be supplied in noaddresses(addresses_arguement) or removed.