# escaping the .each { } iteration early in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator, enumerator

code:

```
 c = 0  
 items.each { |i|  
   puts i.to_s    
   # if c > 9 escape the each iteration early - and do not repeat  
   c++  
 }
```

I want to grab the first 10 items then leave the "each" loop.

What do I replace the commented line with? is there a better approach? something more Ruby idiomatic?

Comment: I suggest nimrodm's answer that uses take: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568288/escaping-the-each-iteration-early-in-ruby/1568445#1568445

Answer (score 62, accepted):

While the `break` solution works, I think a more functional approach really suits this problem. You want to `take` the first 10 elements and print them so try

```
items.take(10).each { |i| puts i.to_s }
```

Comment: Shorter: `puts items.take(10)`

Comment: I tried Googling for 'ruby take method' just now and couldn't find a reference to what module `take` is in.  Where is it in the API?

Comment: I suppose I need to upgrade my Ruby version: `Nothing known about Array#take`

Comment: Or ri Enumerable#take, I suppose. Note that it appears to be new in Ruby 1.9. I get a no method error in Ruby 1.8.6 trying it.

Comment: `Array#take` is present in Ruby 1.8.7 and up.

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 has it, otherwise you can monkey-patch it into Array: `class Array; def take(how_many); self[0..how_many]; end`. AFAIK this is simple and reliable.

Comment: ahhh. I'm down with FP. "You know me!". +1 and answer. I like this better than previous answer. But good to know the break option is there. break lines are easy to comment out during testing.

Answer (score 55):

There is no `++` operator in Ruby.  It's also convention to use `do` and `end` for multi-line blocks.  Modifying your solution yields:

```
c = 0  
items.each do |i|  
  puts i.to_s    
  break if c > 9
  c += 1 
end
```

Or also:

```
items.each_with_index do |i, c|  
  puts i.to_s    
  break if c > 9
end
```

See [`each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003137) and also [Programming Ruby Break, Redo, and Next](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_expressions.html).

**Update:**  [Chuck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568288/escaping-the-each-iteration-early-in-ruby/1568437#1568437) with ranges is more Ruby-like, and [nimrodm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568288/escaping-the-each-iteration-early-in-ruby/1568445#1568445) using `take` is even better.

Comment: Thanks. Answer and +1. Wow I was way off on the initial syntax.

Comment: You weren't far off, really:  the only invalid part of your answer was the `++`.  Curly braces for blocks will work, it's just not preferred for multi-line blocks; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533008/what-is-the-difference-or-value-of-these-block-coding-styles-in-ruby

Comment: I like your first solution because if you want to loop over 100 items every time but only take out 10 conditionally you can increment the counter independently.

Answer (score 8):

`break` works for escaping early from a loop, but it's more idiomatic just to do `items[0..9].each {|i| puts i}`. (And if all you're doing is literally printing the items with no changes at all, you can just do `puts items[0..9]`.)

Comment: I'd have written it as: `puts items[0..9].join("\n")`

Answer (score 4):

Another variant:

```
puts items.first(10)
```

Note that this works fine with arrays of less than 10 items:

```
>> nums = (1..5).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> puts nums.first(10)
1
2
3
4
5
```

(One other note, a lot of people are offering some form of `puts i.to_s`, but in such a case, isn't `.to_s` redundant? `puts` will automatically call `.to_s` on a non-string to print it out, I thought. You would only need `.to_s` if you wanted to say `puts 'A' + i.to_s` or the like.)

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be

```
items.first(10).each do |i|
  puts i.to_s
end
```

That reads a little more easily to me than breaking on an iterator, and first will return only as many items as available if there aren't enough.

Answer (score 1):

Does this look like what you want?

```
10.times { |i|
  puts items[i].to_s
}
```

Comment: That would work, but I won't always be sure that the source has at least 10 items.

Comment: Ah. You can add `break if items[i] == nil` but at this point `each_with_index` is looking like what you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

```
items.each_with_index { |i, c| puts i and break if c <= 9 }
```

Comment: That will break after the first item.

Comment: Not really, how did u test it?

Comment: @Khelll: is this due to lazy evaluation of `and`? It works, but it's a bit too clever for me. My brain keeps wanting `>=` since I see "and break if" together.

Comment: Ok, now I see it: `puts` returns `nil` when it works. Thus, as long as the index is equal to or less than 9, the `puts` happens, `nil` is returned and the second half of the `and` is not evaluated. When the index hits 10, the `puts` doesn't happen and the second half of the `and` gets evaluated. At that point, boom: `break`.

Comment: OK, I had it backwards before, but it's still wrong: This *never* breaks. Look at it like this: `if c <= 9; puts i; break; end`. The `and break` is never executed because `puts i` is always nil and once c>9, the entire body of the if-statement is no longer executed. Replace the `break` with `(puts "YOU WON'T SEE THIS")` if you want to prove that that branch is never reached.

Comment: @Chuck: thanks for one more round. @Khelll: I think we've proven that it doesn't read very naturally.

Answer (score -2):

It was asked:

> I want to grab the first 10 items then leave the "each" loop.

Use `throw` and `catch` to accomplish this, with few changes to the example:

```
catch(:done) do
    c = 0
    collected = []
    items.each do |item|
        collected << item
        throw(:done, collected) if c == 9 # started at 0
        c += 1
    end
    collected # if the list is less than 10 long, return what was collected
end
```

Simply `throw` the label `:done` with `collected` and the `catch` which is waiting for `:done` will return `collected`.

And to "ruby" this up a bit:

```
catch(:done) do
    items.inject([]) do |collected, item|
        throw(:done, collected) if collected.size == 10
        collected << item # collected gets returned here and populates the first argument of this block
    end
end
```

I do not know why some people refuse to use `inject` and use `reduce` instead (they are equivalent) when clearly the empty array given to `inject([])` is being injected with `item`s!  Anyhow, the `inject` will return `collected` if there are less than 10 items.

Most answers are trying to answer what might be the intent of the question instead of what was asked and `items.take(10)` does make perfect sense in that case.  But I can imagine wanting to grab the first items that fit within my $100 budget.  Then you can simply:

```
catch(:done) do
    items.inject({items: [], budget: 100}) do |ledger, item|
        remainder = ledger[:budget] - item.price
        if remainder < 0
            throw(:done, ledger)
        else
            ledger.tap do |this|
                this[:items] << item
                this[:budget] = remainder
            end # tap just returns what is being tapped into, in this case, ledger
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You took a simple question and gave a really complicated answer. There's no need to use `throw` and `catch` here or turn this into 13 lines of deeply nested code. Keep it simple.

Comment: My answer is 6 lines, it shows an alternative way to escape an each loop which was asked, it is nested one level deeper than most of the answers.  My hope in leaving this answer was to show how to alternatively get out of a loop taking advantage of this simple context.  If you had actually read my post, my 13 lines of code is a more complex answer to a more complex example I posed in my answer.  I apologize in advance for having too many words in this response.