# The most idiomatic way to iterate through a Ruby array, exiting when an arbitrary condition met?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, each, break

I want to iterate through an array, each element of which is an array of two integers (e.g. `[3,5]'); for each of these elements, I want to calculate the sum of the two integers, exiting the loop when any of these sums exceeds a certain arbitrary value. The source array is quite large, and I will likely find the desired value near the beginning, so looping through all of the unneeded elements is not a good option.

I have written three loops to do this, all of which produce the desired result. My question is: which is more idiomatic Ruby? Or--better yet--is there a better way? I try not to use non-local loop variables in, but `break` statements look kind of hackish to my (admittedly novice) eye.

```
# Loop A
pairs.each do |pair|
  pair_sum = pair.inject(:+) 
  arr1 << pair_sum
  break if pair_sum > arr2.max
end

#Loop B - (just A condensed)
pairs.each { |pair| arr1.last <= arr2.max ? arr1 << pair.inject(:+) : break }

#Loop C
i = 0
pair_sum = 0
begin
  pair_sum = pairs[i].inject(:+)
  arr1 << pair_sum
  i += 1
end until pair_sum > arr2.max
```

A similar question was asked at [escaping the .each { } iteration early in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568288/escaping-the-each-iteration-early-in-ruby/1568445#1568445), but the responses were essentially that, while using `.each` or `.each_with_index` and exiting with `break` when the target index was reached would work, `.take(num_elements).each` is more idiomatic. In my situation, however, I don't know in advance how many elements I'll have to iterate through, presenting me with what appears to be a boundary case.

This is from a project Euler-type problem I've already solved, btw. Just wondering about the community-preferred syntax. Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Comment: Do you want to print the value for which sum > 6 (say)? or only to test?

Comment: I am pushing the sums of each pair below a certain threshold value to an array for further processing. The only thing printed by the script is a triplet of integers, and that is several steps down the road from here.

Comment: Are the values already sorted?

Comment: I understood but after test you want value as [elem1,elem2,sum],which first cross the threshold value.  right?

Comment: @RubyLovely: After the test, I no longer need to keep up with the values of elem1 or elem2, merely their sum.

Comment: @padde: They are indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`take` and `drop` have a variant `take_while` and `drop_while` where instead of providing a fixed number of elements you provide a block. Ruby will accumulate values from the receiver (in the case of take_while) as long as the block returns true. Your code could be rewritten as

```
array.take_while {|pair| pair.sum < foo}.map(&:sum)
```

This does mean that you calculate the sum of some of these pairs twice.

Comment: Chagrined, I now see that method glaring at me from the bottom of the Array page in the docs, where I'd somehow repeatedly overlooked it. Thanks--exactly the sort of method I assumed was out there somewhere.

Comment: Forgive me if this is obvious, but: the .sum method you used in your code is just a placeholder for some method which produces a sum, and not in some popular module I'm unaware of, right?

Comment: @jdburns: there are several libraries, which monkeypatch a `sum` method to `Enumerable`, e.g. `ActiveSupport`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I thought as much; I monkey-patched my own `product` method to override the built-in Array method in order to make my code more clear to those unfamiliar with Ruby and `.inject` (I guess I could've just made an alias, now that I think about it...). I know that's generally a bad idea, but it was just a toy script.

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby 2.0 there's [`Enumerable#lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) which returns a lazy enumerator:

```
sums = pairs.lazy.map { |a, b| a + b }.take_while { |pair_sum| pair_sum < some_max_value }.force
```

This avoids calculating the sums twice.

Comment: Ah, so THAT'S how lazy enumeration works. I knew it was out there, but hadn't yet played with it and so didn't realize it would be relevant to my situation. Thanks for putting another tool in my belt.

Comment: Although I vaguely recall seeing something saying that lazy enumeration was rather slow in 2.0

Comment: @FrederickCheung In this case, `lazy` is indeed slower than calculating the sum twice. It would be more interesting for expensive operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].find{|x, y| x + y > 6}
# => [3, 4]
```

Comment: Very nice. I wasn't familiar with the `|x,y|' syntax for passing arrays to blocks. That will come in quite handy.

Comment: You can also use `find_all` to find *all* items matching the condition instead of just the first one.

Comment: @padde "I want to calculate the sum of the two integers, exiting the loop when any of these sums exceeds a certain arbitrary value"

Comment: @sawa I wasn't explicit about it in my question (either the site's acting up or my rep is too low to allow me to edit my post), but I do want to push each sum to another array for future use, so find_all would indeed be the method of choice here, as per padde's comment. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].find{|x, y| x + y > 6}.inject(:+)
#=> 7
```

Comment: Combining your input with that of sawa and padde, I come up with:

Comment: Combining your input with that of sawa and padde, I come up with: `s =[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].find_all {|x, y| x + y > 6}.each { |z| arr << z.inject(:+) }`,  which provides the functionality I'm seeking. I'm sure there's a less verbose way of doing this...

Comment: Haha - still learning the ropes. SO cut me off from editing my response in mid-edit. Reposted in full directly above this one.

Comment: The find block will execute for the entire collection (and return all matching elements) so this isn't quite the same

Comment: @FrederickCheung: Ah... excellent point. I'd lost sight of the fact that I was trying to avoid iterating through the entire (massive) array, only with more idiomatic code--which, I now realize, is why I didn't use `find` in the first place.