# Using do block vs braces {}

Tags: ruby, coding-style

New to ruby, put on your newbie gloves.

Is there any difference (obscure or practical) between the following two snippets?

```
my_array = [:uno, :dos, :tres]
my_array.each { |item| 
    puts item
}

my_array = [:uno, :dos, :tres]
my_array.each do |item| 
    puts item
end
```

I realize the brace syntax would allow you to place the block on one line

```
my_array.each { |item| puts item }
```

but outside of that are there any compelling reasons to use one syntax over the other?

Comment: Great question. I'm also interested in what experienced rubyists prefer.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533008

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533008/what-is-the-difference-or-value-of-these-block-coding-styles-in-ruby

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Ruby Block Syntax Error](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6854283/), [Code block passed to `each` works with brackets but not with `do`-`end` (ruby)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6718340/), [Block definition - difference between braces and `do`-`end` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6179442/), [Ruby multiline block without `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3680097/), [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/533008/) and [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/420147/).

Comment: You may also write a one liner of the do block although it's really only useful when doing something like eval("my_array.each do |item|;puts item;end") but it works in irb or pry without eval and quote marks You may come across a situation when that is preferred. Don't ask me when though. That's another topic to be investigated.

Comment: do I really need the DO keyword?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [do..end vs curly braces for blocks in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587264/do-end-vs-curly-braces-for-blocks-in-ruby)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

[Ruby cookbook](http://www.amazon.co.jp/Cookbook-Cookbooks-OReilly-Lucas-Carlson/dp/0596523696) says bracket syntax has higher precedence order than `do..end`

> Keep in mind that the bracket syntax
>   has a higher precedence than the
>   do..end syntax. Consider the following
>   two snippets of code:

```
1.upto 3 do |x|
  puts x
end

1.upto 3 { |x| puts x }
# SyntaxError: compile error
```

Second example only works when parentheses is used, `1.upto(3) { |x| puts x }`

Comment: Ah, got it.  So because of the precedence order, when you use do, you're passing the block as an additional parameter, but when you use the brackets you're passing the block as the first parameter of the results of the method invocation(s) to the left.

Comment: I often prefer short answers but bkdir's answer is much much clearer.

Answer (score 76):

This is a bit old question but I would like to try explain a bit more about `{}` and `do .. end`

like it is said before

> bracket syntax has higher precedence order than do..end

but how this one makes difference:

```
method1 method2 do
  puts "hi"
end
```

in this case, method1 will be called with the block of `do..end` and method2 will be passed to method1 as an argument! which is equivalent to `method1(method2){ puts "hi" }`

but if you say

```
method1 method2{
  puts "hi"
}
```

then method2 will be called with the block then the returned value will be passed to method1 as an argument. Which is equivalent to `method1(method2 do puts "hi" end)`

```
def method1(var)
    puts "inside method1"
    puts "method1 arg = #{var}"
    if block_given?
        puts "Block passed to method1"
        yield "method1 block is running"
    else
        puts "No block passed to method1"
    end
end

def method2
    puts"inside method2"
    if block_given?
        puts "Block passed to method2"
        return yield("method2 block is running")
    else
        puts "no block passed to method2"
        return "method2 returned without block"
    end
end

#### test ####

method1 method2 do 
    |x| puts x
end

method1 method2{ 
    |x| puts x
}
```

#### output ####

```
#inside method2
#no block passed to method2
#inside method1
#method1 arg = method2 returned without block
#Block passed to method1
#method1 block is running

#inside method2
#Block passed to method2
#method2 block is running
#inside method1
#method1 arg = 
#No block passed to method1
```

Answer (score 40):

Generally, the convention is to use `{}` when you are doing a small operation, for example, a method call or a comparison, etc. so this makes perfect sense:

```
some_collection.each { |element| puts element }
```

But if you have slightly complex logic that goes to multiple lines then use `do .. end` like:

```
1.upto(10) do |x|
  add_some_num = x + rand(10)
  puts '*' * add_some_num
end
```

Basically, it comes down to, if your block logic goes to multiple lines and cannot be fitted on the same line then use `do .. end` and if your block logic is simple and just a simple/single line of code then use `{}`.

Comment: I agree with using do/end for multi-line blocks, but I will go with braces if I'm chaining additional methods to the end of the block. Stylistically I like {...}.method().method() over do...end.method().method, but that might just be me.

Comment: Agreed, although I prefer to assign the result of a method with block to a meaningful variable and then call another method on it like `result_with_some_condition = method{|c| c.do_something || whateever}; result_with_some_condition.another_method` as that just makes it a bit more easily understandable. But generally I would avoid a train wreck.

Comment: I wonder, why this style is so popular. Is there any reason for it other than "We always done it this way"?

Answer (score 13):

There are two common styles for choosing `do end` vs. `{ }` for blocks in Ruby:

The first and very common style was popularized by Ruby on Rails, and is based on a simple rule of single vs. multi-line:

- Use braces `{ }` for single-line blocks
- Use `do end` for multi-line blocks

This makes sense because do/end reads badly in a one-liner, but for multi-line blocks, leaving a closing `}` hanging on its own line is inconsistent with everything else that uses `end` in ruby, such as module, class & method definitions (`def` etc.) and control structures (`if`, `while`, `case`, etc.)

The second, less-frequently seen style is known as semantic, or "[Weirich Braces](http://archive.is/96ko8)", proposed by the late, great rubyist Jim Weirich:

- Use `do end` for procedural blocks
- Use braces `{ }` for functional blocks

This means that when the block is evaluated for its *return value*, it should be chainable, and the `{}` braces make more sense for method chaining.

On the other hand, when the block is evaluated for its *side-effects*, then the return value is of no consequence, and the block is just "doing" something, so it does not make sense to be chained.

This distinction in the syntax conveys visual meaning about the evaluation of the block, and whether or not you should care about its return value.

For example, here the return value of the block is applied to every item:

```
items.map { |i| i.upcase }
```

However, here it's not using the block's return value. It's operating procedurally, and *doing* a side-effect with it:

```
items.each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

Another benefit of the semantic style is that you don't need to change braces to do/end just because a line was added to the block.

As an observation, coincidentally *functional* blocks are frequently a one-liner, and *procedural* blocks (e.g. config) are multi-line. So, following the Weirich style ends up looking almost the same as the Rails style.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Weirich style for years, but just moved away from this to **always use braces**. I don't remember to ever have used the info from the block style, and the definition is kinda vague. For example:

```rb
date = Timecop.freeze(1.year.ago) { format_date(Time.now) }
customer = Timecop.freeze(1.year.ago) { create(:customer) }
```

Are these procudual or functional?

And the line count thing is just useless in my opinion. I know, whether there are 1 or more lines, and why exactly should I change the style just because I've added or removed lines?