# Ruby do/end vs braces

Tags: ruby, block

Why does this map expression produce different results depending on whether I use braces or do/end?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]


p a.map { |n|
    n*2
}  
#=> [2,4,6,8,10]


p a.map do |n|
    n*2
end  
#=> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: This holdstrue up to today

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using do block vs braces {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122380/using-do-block-vs-braces)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's because the second line is interpreted as:

```
p(a.map) do ... end
```

instead of:

```
p(a.map do ... end)
```

The grammar is ambiguous in this case and `do` doesn't seem to bind as strongly as `{`.

Comment: @Grandpa It's not particularly about 'p'. It's about the strength/priority between method's taking argument/blocks and {}, do end

Comment: And how is it possible to use `do...end` properly with a multiline block so that `map` gets it as parameter? Braces - as your suggestion - won't do it, Ruby throws an error, `unexpected keyword_do_block` even the whole block is one line.

Comment: @karatedog: You'll probably need to use an intermediate variable here as the parser doesn't support what you want.

Comment: @DarkDust Thanks, but I cannot use an intermediate variable when the Enumerator is infinite because I should have to know beforehand how much items I should generate into that intermediate variable.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, of course you can do `foo = a.map do ... end ; p(foo)`. It is the exact same semantics, because `map` always needs to aggregate an array to pass on first. Whether that array is then stored in a variable or passed as parameter to another method makes no difference, the array needs to be created first no matter what.

Answer (score 4):

That has to do with the difference in associativity of the `{` character and the `do` keyword.

In the first case, the block is interpreted as a block argument to the `map` function. The result of the map function is the argument to the `p` function.

In the second case, the block is interpreted as a block argument to the `p` function, while the `a.map` is interpreted as the first argument to the `p` function. Since `a.map` evaluates to `a`, this prints the original array. The block is effectively ignored in this case.

Answer (score 3):

With the `do/end` syntax you are passing the block to `p` as a second argument, rather than to the map. You get the same result with:

```
p a.map
```

The block is ignored by `p` as it does not produce anything on `inspect`.