# Block doesn't work with `{ }`

Tags: ruby

This one is working

```
[:dev1, :dev2, :dev3].each do |env|
  define_method "#{env.to_s}?" do  
    settings.environment == env
  end
end
```

but this is not

```
[:dev1, :dev2, :dev3].each do |env|
  define_method "#{env.to_s}?" { settings.environment == env }
end
```

it causes the error because of using `{ ... }` syntax. why?

Comment: I think this should work without problem. Your context is in ruby-on-rails, right? I have edited the tags.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513531/ruby-do-end-vs-braces

Comment: @Alexandre: sorry then. My bad. Reverting my edit

Comment: It is not solely Boris's fault. The question was confusing in including unnecessary things like `helpers`. Questions should be user friendly, not including anything unnecessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is probably because the method takes other arguments besides a block, and you're omitting parentheses.

Try it this way:

```
define_method("#{env.to_s}?") { settings.environment == env }
```