# Calling 'puts' on an expression changing the way it's interpreted?

Tags: ruby

I just ran into an issue where the value returned by a function is different depending on whether or not I call puts on that result.  I'm wondering if this is to be expected, or some sort of parser error.

This only occurs if the block passed to the function uses the `do...end` syntax, not the inline `{...}` syntax.  Here's an example:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
puts i = arr.index { |x| == "b" }
#=> 1
```

as expected, but this does not work as I'd expect:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
puts i = arr.index do |x|
  x == "b"
end
#=> #<Enumerator:0xSomeId>
```

Though it works fine if I do:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
i = arr.index do |x|
  x == "b"
end
puts i
#=> 1
```

It looks like it's interpreted as if it were passed no block at all (returning the enumerator is the expected behavior of calling `arr.index` with block).  Is this normal?  Is this behavior explained/documented anywhere?

Comment: It's due to `{ ... }` having a higher precedence than `do ... end`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122380/using-do-block-vs-brackets

Comment: Use `arr.index("b")` then you don't have to worry about it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`do...end` blocks associate with the leftmost method while `{...}` blocks associate with the rightmost, due to precedence. In your second example, the block is being associated with `puts`, which does nothing with it.

It seems like weird behavior in this case, but it's this feature of `do...end` blocks that give a lot of Ruby [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)'s their clean, readable syntax.

Comment: Usually this isn't an issue because each line should be performing a specific operation. Grouping too many things together not only confuses other developers, but may also confuse the parser.

Answer (score 2):

`{ ... }` binds more tightly than `do ... end`, so your `do ... end` block ends up attached to `IO#puts` (which ignores it) and not `Array#index`.

If you put then parens into the `puts() call` you can see:

```
puts(i = arr.index do |x| x == 'b' end)
```