# Why can't I print the result of an enumerable method in ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is the code:

```
def count_ones(number, num_bits)
      (0...num_bits).inject(0) { |total, shift| total + (number >> shift & 1) }
end

puts (0...gets.to_i).map do 
    start, finish = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
    (start..finish).inject(0) { |total, number| total + count_ones(number, 32) }
end
```

If I input 3, I would expect to be able to input 3 more times.  Instead it prints out an enumerable object..

But.. if I do this, and input 3 :

```
puts (0...gets.to_i).map { |i| i }
```

I get the result I'm expecting:
0
1
2

How can I reconcile these contradictory behaviors with one and other?

Comment: what version of Ruby?

Comment: 2.0.0   (15 characters)

Comment: Interesting, something must have changed after 1.8.x. I don't get an enumerable in 1.8.7 but I do in 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I figured it out:  It was actually the usage of do/end as opposed to curly brackets.  This code actually evaluates and prints the block how I expect it to:

```
def count_ones(number, num_bits)
      (0...num_bits).inject(0) { |total, shift| total + (number >> shift & 1) }
end

puts (0...gets.to_i).map {
    start, finish = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
    (start..finish).inject(0) { |total, number| total + count_ones(number, 32) }
}
```

Very interesting, because until now I had thought that curly brackets and do/end were semantically equivalent.

Comment: It's because they have different precedence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122380/using-do-block-vs-brackets

Comment: [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587264/do-end-vs-curly-braces-for-blocks-in-ruby) about the difference between `do..end` and `{..}`.

Comment: Not only they differ in precedence. I had a question where I couldn't translate nested curly brace blocks into do/end blocks __at all__: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424778/ruby-curly-braces-vs-do-end-method-chaining