# Ruby custom sorting returns -1 +1 instead of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to implement my first ruby sorting algorithm. This algorithm is based on some specific rules ("always prefer objects of type xxx over objects of types yyy"), and if none of these rules triggered, it uses the ruby <=>-operator. I'm doing this on a ruby-on-rails one-to-many association.

The problem is this algortihm does not return the array itself, it just returns -1 or 1, the result of the comparison..But I actually don't understand why, as my result is only returned in the sort-block.

Here is my current code:

```
def sort_products!
  products.sort! do |p1, p2|
    result = 0

    # Scalable Products are always the last ones in order
    if p1.class.name == "ScalableProduct"
      result = -1
    elsif p2.class.name == "ScalableProduct"
      result = 1
    end

    if result == 0
      # Put products producing electricity and heating down
      if p1.can_deliver_electricity?
        result = -1
      elsif p2.can_deliver_electricity? 
        result = 1
      end
    end

    # Else: Just compare names
    result = p1.name <=> p2.name if result == 0
    result
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the code that calls that method?

Comment: plz print out the products array inside the sort_products! method before it is calling the sort! method.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice here, in my opinion, would be to implement the `<=>` inside the `Product` model. You'll need to include the `Comparable` model in order to achive this:

```
class Product
  include Comparable

  def <=>(another_product)
    # Compare self with another_product
    # Return -1, 0, or 1
  end
end
```

Then your sorting method will be reduced to:

```
def sort_products!
  products.sort!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `do..end` for brackets as delimiters of the block. It is first sorting, and then using the block on the result (because of the [precedence of the do..end syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122380/using-do-block-vs-brackets)). Using brackets, it uses the block *as a sorting block*, which is what you wanted.

Also, in your comparison, if both your products are `ScalableProduct` then you will not order them in a sensible way. If they are both `ScalableProduct` at the same time, you might want to keep `result` as `0` so it falls back to comparing by name. Same deal with `can_deliver_electricity?`.