# Basic ruby question: the { } vs do/end construct for blocks

Tags: ruby, programming-languages, syntax

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Using do block vs brackets {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122380/using-do-block-vs-brackets)
>   [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533008/what-is-the-difference-or-value-of-these-block-coding-styles-in-ruby)

Why does:

```
test = [1, 1, 1].collect do |te|
    te + 10
end
puts test
```

Works, but not:

```
puts test = [1, 1, 1].collect do |te|
    te + 10
end
```

And yet this works:

```
puts test = [1, 1, 1].collect { |te|
    te + 10
}
```

Is there a difference between the do/end construct and the { } construct for blocks I am not aware of?

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/533008/ and http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/2122380/ and probably a dozen others.

Comment: Most upvoted duplicate I saw : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587264/do-end-vs-curly-braces-for-blocks-in-ruby/5587403

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the "not working" case, the block is actually attached to the `puts` call, not to the `collect` call. `{}` binds more tightly than `do`.

The explicit brackets below demonstrate the difference in the way Ruby interprets the above statements:

```
puts(test = [1, 1, 1].collect) do |te|
    te + 10
end

puts test = ([1, 1, 1].collect {|te|
    te + 10
})
```

Comment: Is there a general rule you can follow to predict this kind of behavior?

Comment: Well, to be sure, check the precedence rules (http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4).   But as a rule of thumb, I always treat do...end as a code block, and {} as a function; also, never put a do...end inside a {}.