# do..end vs curly braces for blocks in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coding-style

I have a coworker who is actively trying to convince me that I should not use do..end and instead use curly braces for defining multiline blocks in Ruby.

I'm firmly in the camp of only using curly braces for short one-liners and do..end for everything else. But I thought I would reach out to the greater community to get some resolution.

So which is it, and why? (Example of some shoulda code)

```
context do
  setup { do_some_setup() }
  should "do somthing" do
    # some more code...
  end
end
```

or

```
context {
  setup { do_some_setup() }
  should("do somthing") {
    # some more code...
  }
}
```

Personally, just looking at the above answers the question for me, but I wanted to open this up to the greater community.

Comment: Just wondering but what are your coworkers' arguments for using braces? Seems more like a personal preference than a logic thing.

Comment: If you want a discussion make it a community wiki. To your question: It's just personal style. I prefer the curly braces as they look more nerdy.

Comment: It isn't a preference thing, there are syntactic reasons for using one over the other in addition to stylistic reasons. Several of the answers explain why. Failing to use the right one can cause very subtle bugs that are hard to find if another "stylistic" choice is made to never use wrapping parenthesis for methods.

Comment: Wow, some great answers, I didn't expect so much. For my own sake, I want to point out I wasn't oblivious to the precedence difference. I just believe an edge condition that would only effect the outcome of 1% of my code shouldn't have that great of an effect on how I style the other 99%. When and if it mattered, I'd make exception from whatever style detected.

Comment: "Edge conditions" have a bad habit of sneaking up on people who don't know about them. Coding defensively means a lot of things, including deciding to use coding styles that minimize the chance of ever running into the cases. YOU might be aware, but the guy two people after you might not be after the tribal knowledge has been forgotten. It tends to happen in corporate environments unfortunately.

Comment: @tinman These types of edge conditions are handled by TDD. This is why Rubist can write code like this and get a full nights rest knowing such errors don't exists in their code. When developing with TDD or BDD and such a mistake in precedence is made the red shown on the screen is what reminds us of the "tribal knowledge". Usually the solution is to add a couple of parens somewhere which is totally acceptable within the standard conventions. :)

Comment: @BlakeTaylor Sorry, but saying that these cases are handled by TDD is just not true. I just got bitten by this **in a test** and spent half an hour debugging it :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using do block vs braces {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122380/using-do-block-vs-braces)

Comment: Real world example. I recently had to dust off ERB template writing and spent a bit of time "remembering" why `content_tag('div') do; concat 'outer content'; concat content_tag('p') do; concat 'some inner content'; concat 'some other inner content'; end; end` (on multiple lines, not squished into one like this) wasn't appending any of the inner content, until i remembered the precedence. `{}` is what I needed to have the block apply to the `content_tag('p')` and not the `concat`.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

The general convention is to use do..end for multi-line blocks and curly braces for single line blocks, but there is also a difference between the two that can be illustrated with this example:

```
puts [1,2,3].map{ |k| k+1 }
2
3
4
=> nil
puts [1,2,3].map do |k| k+1; end
#<Enumerator:0x0000010a06d140>
=> nil
```

This means that {} has a higher precedence than do..end, so keep that in mind when deciding what you want to use.

One more example to keep in mind while you develop your preferences.

The following code:

```
task :rake => pre_rake_task do
  something
end
```

really means:

```
task(:rake => pre_rake_task){ something }
```

And this code:

```
task :rake => pre_rake_task {
  something
}
```

really means:

```
task :rake => (pre_rake_task { something })
```

So to get the actual definition that you want, with curly braces, you must do:

```
task(:rake => pre_rake_task) {
  something
}
```

Maybe using braces for parameters is something you want to do anyways, but if you don't it's probably best to use do..end in these cases to avoid this confusion.

Comment: Why does `puts [1,2,3].map do |k| k+1; end` only print the enumerator i.e. one thing. Isn't puts passed two arguments here namely `[1,2,3].map` and `do |k| k+1; end`?

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/1520

f = lambda do |param|
  ...
end
scope :some_scope, f

Maybe this looks unidiomatic, and then there's the other alternative, which I thinks is ugly:

scope :some_scope, (lambda do |param|
  ...
end)

Comment: `[1,2,3].map do |k| puts k+1 end` seems more readable then `puts [1,2,3].map { |k| k+1 }`

Comment: @ben: exactly, because it is `puts` that gets two parameters. First `.map` gets evaluated, but it did not get a block (as the thing that looks like a block is not `.map`'s argument), so it returns an enumerator which becomes `puts` first argument. And `puts` will get that block as 2nd argument, but `puts` does not use any passed block, so there happens nothing. Parentheses fix this problem: `puts ([1,2,3].map do |k| k+1; end)`

Answer (score 61):

From [Programming Ruby](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#blocksclosuresandprocobjects):

> Braces have a high precedence; do has a low precedence. If the method invocation has parameters that are not enclosed in parentheses, the brace form of a block will bind to the last parameter, not to the overall invocation. The do form will bind to the invocation.

So the code

```
f param {do_something()}
```

Binds the block to the `param` variable while the code

```
f param do do_something() end
```

Binds the block to the function `f`.

However this is a non-issue if you enclose function arguments in parenthesis.

Answer (score 16):

There a few points of view on this, it's really a matter of personal preference. Many rubyists take the approach you do. However, two other styles that are common is to always use one or the other, or to use `{}` for blocks that return values, and `do ... end` for blocks that are executed for side effects.

Comment: It isn't a matter of personal preference only. Binding of parameters can cause subtle bugs if method params aren't enclosed in parenthesis.

Answer (score 9):

The most common rule I've seen (most recently in [Eloquent Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321584104)) is:

- If it's a multi-line block, use do/end
- If it's a single line block, use {}

Answer (score 8):

#### I'm voting for do / end

---

The convention is `do .. end` for multiline and `{ ... }` for one-liners.

But I like `do .. end` better, so when I have a one liner, I use `do .. end` anyway but format it as usual for do/end in three lines. This makes everyone happy.

```
  10.times do 
    puts ...
  end
```

One problem with `{ }` is that it is poetry-mode-hostile (because they bind tightly to the last parameter and not the entire method call, so you must include method parens) and they just, to my mind, don't look as nice. They are not statement-groups and they clash with hash constants for readability.

Plus, I've seen enough of `{ }` in C programs. Ruby's way, as usual, is better. There is exactly one type of `if` block, and you never have to go back and convert a statement into a compound-statement.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is another "if" syntax - the postfix "if" (`do_stuff if x==1`), which is kind of annoying to convert to the regular syntax. But that's another discussion.

Comment: There are prefix `if`, postfix `if`, postfix `unless` (also a kind of `if`, a if-not) and one line `if` with `then`. The Ruby way is to have plenty of ways to express in fact something that is always the same thing, much worse than what C is offering that follows very simple, strict rules.

Answer (score 7):

A couple influential rubyists suggest to use braces when you use the return value, and do/end when you don't.

[http://talklikeaduck.denhaven2.com/2007/10/02/ruby-blocks-do-or-brace](http://web.archive.org/web/20121226012902/http://talklikeaduck.denhaven2.com/2007/10/02/ruby-blocks-do-or-brace) (on archive.org)

[http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/BraceVsDoEnd.rdoc](http://web.archive.org/web/20140221124509/http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/BraceVsDoEnd.rdoc) (on archive.org)

This seems like a good practice in general.

I'd modify this principle a bit to say that you should avoid using do/end on a single line because it's harder to read.

You do have to be more careful using braces because it'll bind to a method's final param instead of the whole method call. Just add parentheses to avoid that.

Answer (score 7):

There is one major benefit to curly braces - many editors have a MUCH easier time of matching them, making certain types of debugging much easier. Meanwhile, the keyword "do...end" is quite a bit harder to match, especially since "end"s also match "if"s.

Comment: RubyMine for example, highlight `do ... end` keywords by default

Comment: While I do prefer braces, I see no reason that an editor would have trouble finding a 2/3 character string versus a single character. Though there is the argument that most editors already match braces, whereas `do ... end` is a special case which requires language specific logic.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's a personal preference, but having said that, for past 3 years of my ruby experiences what I have learnt is that ruby has its style.

One example would be, if you are comming from a JAVA background , for a boolean method you might use

```
def isExpired
  #some code
end
```

notice the camel case and most often 'is' prefix to identify it as a boolean method.

But in ruby world, the same method would be

```
def expired?
  #code
end
```

so I personally think, it's better to go with 'ruby way' (But I know it takes some time for one to understand (it took me around 1 year :D)).

Finally, I would go with

```
do 
  #code
end
```

blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I put another Answer, although the *big* difference was already pointed out (prcedence/binding), and that can cause hard to find problems (the Tin Man, and others pointed that out). 
I think my example shows the problem with a not so usual code snippet, even experienced programmeres do not read like the sunday times:

```
module I18n
    extend Module.new {
        old_translate=I18n.method(:translate)
        define_method(:translate) do |*args|
            InplaceTrans.translate(old_translate, *args)
        end
        alias :t :translate
    }
end

module InplaceTrans
    extend Module.new {
        def translate(old_translate, *args)
            Translator.new.translate(old_translate, *args)
        end
    }
end
```

Then i did some code beautifying ...

```
#this code is wrong!
#just made it 'better looking'
module I18n
    extend Module.new do
        old_translate=I18n.method(:translate)
        define_method(:translate) do |*args|
            InplaceTrans.translate(old_translate, *args)
        end
        alias :t :translate
    end
end
```

if you change the `{}` here to `do/end` you will get the error, that method `translate` does not exist ...

Why this happens is pointed out here more than one - precedence. But where to put braces here? (@the Tin Man: I always use braces, like you, but here ... overseen)

so every answer like

> ```
> If it's a multi-line block, use do/end
> If it's a single line block, use {}
> ```

is just *wrong* if used without the "BUT Keep an eye on braces / precedence!"

again:

```
extend Module.new {} evolves to extend(Module.new {})
```

and

```
extend Module.new do/end evolves to extend(Module.new) do/end
```

(what ever the result of extend does with the block ...)

So if you want to use do/end use this:

```
#this code is ok!
#just made it 'better looking'?
module I18n
    extend(Module.new do 
        old_translate=I18n.method(:translate)
        define_method(:translate) do |*args|
            InplaceTrans.translate(old_translate, *args)
        end
        alias :t :translate
    end)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Comes down to personal bias, I prefer curly braces over a do/end block as its more understandable to a higher number of developers due to a majority of background languages use them over the do/end convention. With that being said the real key is to come to an agreement within your shop, if do/end is used by 6/10 developers than EVERYONE should be using them, if 6/10 use curly braces, then stick to that paradigm.

Its all about making a pattern so that the team as a whole can identify the code structures quicker.

Comment: It is more than preference. The binding between the two is different and can cause problems that are hard to diagnose. Several of the answers detail the problem.

Comment: In terms of people of other language backgrounds - I think the difference in "understandability" is so small in this case as to not warrant consideration. (That wasn't my downvote btw.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference between them, but { } binds tighter than do/end.

Answer (score 0):

My personal style is to emphasize readability over rigid rules of `{`...`}` vs `do`...`end` choice, when such choice is possible. My idea of readability is as follows:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ].map { |e| e + 1 }      # preferred
[ 1, 2, 3 ].map do |e| e + 1 end   # acceptable

[ 1, 2, 3 ].each_with_object [] do |e, o| o << e + 1 end # preferred, reads like a sentence
[ 1, 2, 3 ].each_with_object( [] ) { |e, o| o << e + 1 } # parens make it less readable

Foo = Module.new do     # preferred for a multiline block, other things being equal
  include Comparable
end

Foo = Module.new {      # less preferred
  include Comparable
}

Foo = Module.new { include Comparable }      # preferred for a oneliner
Foo = module.new do include Comparable end   # imo less readable for a oneliner

[ [ 1 ], [ 1, 2 ] ].map { |e| e.map do |e| e + 1 end }  # slightly better
[ [ 1 ], [ 1, 2 ] ].map { |e| e.map { |e| e + 1 } }     # slightly worse
```

In more complex syntax, such as multiline nested blocks, I try to intersperse `{`...`}` and `do`...`end` delimiters for most natural result, eg.

```
Foo = Module.new { 
  if true then
    Bar = Module.new {                          # I intersperse {} and keyword delimiters
      def quux
        "quux".tap do |string|                  # I choose not to intersperse here, because
          puts "(#{string.size} characters)"    # for multiline tap, do ... end in this
        end                                     # case still loks more readable to me.
      end
    }
  end
}
```

Although the lack of rigid rules might produce sligtly different choices for different programmers, I believe that case-by-case optimization for readability, although subjective, is a net gain over adherence to rigid rules.

Answer (score -1):

I took an example of the most voted answer here. Say,

```
[1,2,3].map do 
  something 
end
```

If you check what internal implementation in array.rb, *map method's header says*:

`Invokes the given block once for each element of self.`

```
def map(*several_variants)
    (yield to_enum.next).to_enum.to_a
end
```

i.e. it accepts a block of code - whatever is in between **do** and **end** is executed as yield. Then the result is going to be collected as array again, thus it's returning a completely new object.

> So Whenever you encounter a **do-end** block or **{ }**, just have a
>   mind map that the block of code is being passed as a parameter, which
>   will be getting executed internally.

Answer (score -3):

There's a third option: Write a preprocessor to infer "end" on its own line, from indentation. The deep thinkers who prefer concise code happen to be right.

Better yet, hack ruby so this is a flag.

Of course, the "pick your fights" simplest solution is to adopt the style convention that a sequence of ends all appear on the same line, and teach your syntax coloring to mute them. For ease of editing, one could use editor scripts to expand/collapse these sequences.

20% to 25% of my ruby code lines are "end" on their own line, all trivially inferred by my indentation conventions. Ruby is the lisp-like language to have achieved the greatest success. When people dispute this, asking where are all the ghastly parentheses, I show them a ruby function ending in seven lines of superfluous "end".

I did code for years using a lisp preprocessor to infer most parentheses: A bar '|' opened a group that autoclosed at the end of the line, and a dollar sign '$' served as an empty placeholder where there would otherwise be no symbols to help infer the groupings. This is of course religious war territory. Lisp/scheme without the parentheses is the most poetic of all languages. Still, it is easier to simply quiet down parentheses using syntax coloring.

I still code with a preprocessor for Haskell, to add heredocs, and to default all flush lines as comments, everything indented as code. I dislike comment characters, whatever the language.