# syntax error unexpected keyword_end expecting '}' SHOES

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, shoes

My Son made a program for fun with Shoes, which is basically the same as ruby but has a gui. (only difference i know in syntax is *alert* instead of *puts*.) He got errors while running it ans looked to me. I can't find the cause of all these errors. And the *'s are substitutes for classified info.

Thank You

```
Shoes.app do
 #revised lines 1-17
 line = ask "Password (lowercase)"
  if line == "password"
     #superuser password for fast login
     alert "Logged In"
     name = ask "Name (lowercase)"
      if name == "***"
         alert "Welcome, ***"
         alert "Now, please verify your identity"
         idconfirm = ask "What is your 4 digit ID number; if unknown, type 'u'"
          if idconfirm == "u"
             alert "Please contact *** immediatly at ********@gmail.com"
          end
          if idconfirm == "******"
             alert "Administrator Code accepted"
             alert "What do you wish to do now?"
             stack(:align => "center") { #stack is for buttons
                 button "Latest projects (bip)" do
                     stack(:align => "center") { #stack is for paragraph and buttons
                         para "==================================================================
                         build an IRC bot FRAMEWORK
                         learn more languages
                         tri-boot?
                         backup files for win 8 clousre (WHEN NECESSARY)"
                         button "Rblx Assignments" {
                             rblxconf = ask "PASSCODE"
                              if rblxconf == "***********"
                                 #not FINISHED continue                           
                                 para(:align => "center") #CHECK LINE PARA_NTHESES
                                 "===============================================================
                                 learn roblox script
                                 build own admin script
                                 build roblox ***
                                 find other ways to *******"
                              else
                               alert "Not Correct" #revise alert
                              end
                            }
                        }
                   end
                 button "WELCOME"
                }
       end


#revised  up to here CONFIRMED
         if idconfirm == "****"
             alert "Thank You, ***. What do you want to do now?"
             stack(:align => "center") do #stack is for buttons
                 button "Latest projects (bip)" do
                     stack(:align => "center") {
                         para "==================================================================
                         build an IRC bot FRAMEWORK
                         learn more languages
                         tri-boot?
                         backup files for win 8 clousre (WHEN NECESSARY)"
                         button "Rblx Assignments" {
                             rblxconf = ask "PASSCODE"
                             if rblxconf == "***********"
                                 #not FINISHED continue                           
                                 para(
                                 :align => "center")
                                 "===============================================================
                                 learn roblox script
                                 build own admin script
                                 build roblox ***
                                 find other ways to *******"
                             else 
                              alert "Not Correct"
                             end
                            }
                        }
                    end
                 button "WELCOME"
                 button "Admin Log In" do
                     adminconfirm = ask "Admin Code (Hint:MMORPG accounts)"
                      if adminconfirm == "******" 
                         alert "Administrator Code accepted"
                         alert "What do you wish to do now"
                         #IN PROGRESS
                      end
                 end
             end
         end
      else
       alert "Your name is not registered"
      end      
  #superuser password for fast login
  else
   alert "Wrong Password"
  end
 #REVISED UP TO HERE [CONFIRMED]

 # +=========================================================================================================================================================
 #REVISE EVERYTHING OK?
 #revise 25 39 42 55 78 82 & 86 and more ;P
end
```

Comment: Paste the full exception - it should include a reference to the line number there's a problem on.

Comment: Your identation is a bit all over the place - these things are a lot easier to spot with consistent indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching all of your '{' to 'do' and your '}' to 'end'. I stopped getting the errors once I did that.

Not having any shoes experience, I am not sure why it matters. But there are minor differences between the two - see [do..end vs curly braces for blocks in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587264/do-end-vs-curly-braces-for-blocks-in-ruby).