# Rspec: How to stub a method evaluated in a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following code (removed unrelated parts):

```
# Picture.rb
image_accessor :image_file do
  puts "config: #{Config.get(:preprocess_image_resize).present?}"
end
```

image_accessor is provided by [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly).

I want to stub `Config.get` (which works great for many other specs in other scenarios), but here it does not have any effect.

This is the test:

```
it "should resize the image file to the given value" do
  Config.stub!(:get) { |arg| arg == :preprocess_image_resize ? '1x1' : false }
end
```

When running the test I expect to see "config: true" in the console.
But I always get "config: false".

I cant explain why - perhaps because of the evaluation in the block?

Any ideas how to stub this then?

Comment: How/when is the picture being instantiated? That it's in a block in itself shouldn't matter.

Comment: The picture is being instantiated in the spec, after the stub.

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of those weird cases where [do...end and curly braces are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5587264/473467) in Ruby.

If so, the block is being run **after** `Config.stub!(:get)` which in that case returns `nil`. That would explain why `Config.get(:preprocess_image_resize).present?` is always `false`.

My advice: Try changing the code to

```rb
it "should resize the image file to the given value" do
  Config.stub!(:get) do |arg|
    arg == :preprocess_image_resize ? '1x1' : false
  end
end
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't this be precisely the same thing?

Comment: No, it's not. `do...end` and curly braces are of  different precedence. Read the linked answer :)