# Iterating over a multidimensional array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

```
class Lod

attr_accessor :lodnr
attr_accessor :lobnr
attr_accessor :stknr

def initialize(lodnr, lobnr, stknr)
    @lodnr = lodnr
    @lobnr = lobnr
    @stknr = stknr.chomp
end

def to_s
    "%8s, %5s, %3s" % [@lodnr, @lobnr, @stknr]
end
end
```

I have an array called `sold` which contains these four arrays:

```
[10000, 150, 5]
[500, 10, 1]
[8000, 171, 3]
[45, 92, 4]
```

The four arrays are objects of a class, imported from at .txt file.

```
    input = File.open("lodsedler.txt", "r")
input.each do |line|
    l = line.split(',')
    if l[0].to_i.between?(0, 99999) && l[1].to_i.between?(1, 180) && l[2].to_i.between?(1, 10)
        sold << Lod.new(l[0], l[1], l[2])
    else
        next
    end
end
```

I want to count the first value in each array, looking for a randomly selected number which is stored in `first`.

The error I get is always something like this, whatever i try:

```
Undefined method xxx for #Lod:0x0000000022e2d48> (NoMethodError)
```

The problem is that i can't seem to acces the first value in all the arrays.

Comment: Where does this Lod class come into the picture? Your description says these are arrays, not Lod objects. Are the numbers actually meant to be Lod objects or what?

Comment: Sorry, yes the inner arrays are Lod objects imported from text file:
        input = File.open("lodsedler.txt", "r")
     input.each do |line|
  l = line.split(',')
  if l[0].to_i.between?(0, 99999) && l[1].to_i.between?(1, 180) && l[2].to_i.between?(1, 10)
   $sold << Lod.new(l[0], l[1], l[2])
  else
   next
  end

Answer (score 6):

You could try

```
a = [[10000, 150, 5], [500, 10, 1],[8000, 171, 3],[45, 92, 4]]
```

You can access a[0][0] 10000 or a[2][1] 171 or iterate

```
a.each do |row|
  row.each do |column|
      puts column  
  end
end
```

Edit for comment regarding using braces instead of do:

Sure it's possible but I believe do..end in preferred: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5587403/514463

```
a.each { |row|
  row.each { |column|
      puts column  
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to print that using .each loop and blocks without using do keyword. Something like `a.each { |one_dimention|  one_dimention.each { |number| puts number } }`

Comment: Please consider updating your answer if the above is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to get the first element of each sub array is to use transpose:

```
special_number = 45
array = [
  [10000, 150, 5],
  [500, 10, 1],
  [8000, 171, 3],
  [45, 92, 4]
]

p array.transpose.first.count(special_number) #=> 1
```

Edit: Actually simpler and more direct...

```
p array.map(&:first).count(special_number) #=> 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the `.transpose`