# Does Ruby read "do" and "end" the same way as "{" and "}"?

Tags: ruby, syntax, lambda, block

There are two different syntax for writing blocks in Ruby. There's

```
do |something|
    ...
end
```

and there's also

```
{ |something|
    ...
}
```

I realized that what this is doing is just replacing the keywords "do" and "end" with brackets. This made me wonder, when Ruby works with these two syntax, is there any significant difference in the way it handles them. Or does Ruby handle them the same way, interchangeably? If they're totally interchangeable, then why include both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [do..end vs curly braces for blocks in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587264/do-end-vs-curly-braces-for-blocks-in-ruby)

Comment: @falsetru, this is not a duplicate. This question asks whether (and when) are `do`...`end` and `{`...`}` are interchangeable. The question you link is concerned with style, it asks which ones to use when they _are_ interchangeable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it doesn't. As a general rule of Ruby, if two things look alike, you can bet that there is a subtle difference between them, which makes each of them unique and necessary.

`{` and `}` do not always stand in the role of block delimiters. When they do not stand in the role of block delimiters (such as when constructing hashes, `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`), they cannot be replaced by `do` ... `end`. But when the curly braces do delimit a block, they can almost always be replaced by `do` ... `end`. But beware, because sometimes this can change the meaning of your statement. This is because `{` ... `}` have higher precedence, they bind tighter than `do` ... `end`:

```
puts [ 1, 2, 3 ].map { |e| e + 1 }         # { ... } bind with #map method
2
3
4
#=> nil

puts [ 1, 2, 3 ].map do |e| e + 1 end      # do ... end bind with #puts method
#<Enumerator:0x0000010a06d140>
#=> nil
```

As for the opposite situation, `do` ... `end` in the role of block delimiters cannot always be replaced by curly braces.

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ].each_with_object [] do |e, obj| obj << e.to_s end  # is possible
[ 1, 2, 3 ].each_with_object [] { |e, obj| obj << e.to_s }   # invalid syntax
```

In this case, you would have to parenthesize the ordered argument:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ].each_with_object( [] ) { |e, obj| obj << e.to_s }  # valid with ( )
```

The consequence of these syntactic rules is that you can write this:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ].each_with_object [ nil ].map { 42 } do |e, o| o << e end
#=> [ 42, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

And the above also demonstrates the case where `{}` are not replaceable by `do`/`end`:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ].each_with_object [ nil ].map do 42 end do |e, o| o << e end
#=> SyntaxError
```

Lambda syntax with `->` differs slightly in that it equally accepts both:

```
foo = -> x do x + 42 end  # valid
foo = -> x { x + 42 }     # also valid
```

Furthermore, `do` and `end` themselves do not always delimit a block. In particular, this

```
for x in [ 1, 2, 3 ] do
  puts x
end
```

and this

```
x = 3
while x > 0 do
  x -= 1
end
```

and this

```
x = 3
until x == 0 do
  x -= 1
end
```

superficially contains `do` ... `end` keywords, but there is no real block between them. The code inside them does not introduce a new scope, it is just syntax used to repeat a few statements. Curly braces cannot be used here, and the syntax could be written without `do`, such as:

```
for x in [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  puts x
end

# same for while and until
```

For the cases where `{`...`}` and `do`...`end` delimiters are interchangeable, the choice which ones to use is a matter of programming style, and is [extensively discussed in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587264/do-end-vs-curly-braces-for-blocks-in-ruby) (from whose accepted answer I took one of my examples here). My personal preference in such case is to emphasize readability over rigid rules.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for such a well-though-out and well-considered answer! I'm going to take some time to digest this. I may ask a couple of follow-up questions.

Comment: It takes time for a Rubyist to figure all of this.

Comment: What about `begin end`, any difference from `do end` ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the `{ }` block syntax is used for single-line blocks, and the `do ... end` syntax is used for multi-line blocks. One difference between the two is that your parameters must be inside parenthesis for curly-brace blocks. Example:

`some_method(param1, param2) { ... }`

```
some_method param1, param2 do
   ...
end
```

Comment: `"123".gsub /./ do |s| (s.to_i + 1).to_s end => "234"`, but `"123".gsub /./ { |s| (s.to_i + 1).to_s }` raises a syntax error. On the other hand, `[1,2,3].each_with_object [] { |e,a| a << e + 1 } => [2, 3, 4]`. Know why?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No idea, can't find it in the block spec either.

Comment: Because Ruby parser needs some hint for whether `{` is beginning of a hash or a block. Ruby parser tries to parse `some_method p1, p2, {...}` as a hash param, not block; on the other end, it treats `some_method {...}` as block param.