# Different behavior with map, select, etc. when using do...end blocks

Tags: ruby

I noticed following difference in behavior when I use `map`, `select`, and other [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) methods.

Let's assume we have a hash like below:

```
h = {a: 1}
```

Below code prints the output of `select` as expected.

```
p h.select { |k, v| true }
#=> {:a=>1}
```

However, below code shows that output is an `Enumerator`, even when a block has been provided.

```
p h.select do |k, v| 
  true 
end
#=> #<Enumerator: {:a=>1}:select>
```

Any idea why this difference of behavior?  I run into this issue often as I keep using inspect `p` while working, and this behavior derails my thought process quite often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator precedence matters.

```
p h.select do |k, v| true end
```

is in fact executed as:

```
(p h.select) do |k, v| true end
```

while

```
p h.select { |k, v| true }
```

is treated as:

```
p (h.select { |k, v| true })
```

`Enumerable#select`, called without a block, returns an enumerator.

Comment: Whats the way out, I need to put  parenthesis around it to resolve the precedence.

Comment: It is completely up to you. And, yes, parenthesis will work.

Comment: It may not be operator precedence, may be how parameters to function call are interpreted.  Is it more likely that evaluation happened as `p(h.inspect) do..end`  instead of `(p h.select) do ...end`?

Answer (score 2):

I think @mudasobwa's answer is essentially correct, but I wanted to clarify what's actually happening with regard to precedence.

When you do this:

```
p h.select do |k, v| 
  true 
end
```

...you're actually doing this:

```
p(h.select) do |k, v| 
  true 
end
```

In other words, you're passing the result of `h.select` (with no arguments, which returns an Enumerator) as an argument to `p` and you're also passing a block argument to `p`. `p` apparently silently ignores the block argument.

Conversely, when you do this:

```
p h.select {|k, v| true }
```

...you're actually doing this:

```
p(h.select {|k, v| true })
```

That is, you're passing the result of `h.select { |k, v| true }` to `p`, which gives you the result you expect.

If you want to use the `do...end` syntax and get the result you want, you have to wrap the whole thing in parentheses:

```
p(h.select do |k, v| 
  true 
end)
```

It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Any idea why would `do...end` and `{...}` both are not treated as blocks to `p` as shown in first case of your answer

Comment: Don't worry,  I got answer about it from another [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587264/do-end-vs-curly-braces-for-blocks-in-ruby).

Comment: I can't explain it except to say that it's how the parser works. There may be some technical reason, but I suspect it was simply a design choice. There's a good use case for each style, but it's unfortunate that it catches people off guard sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation website

> Returns a new hash consisting of entries for which the block returns true.
>
> If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

Here is the code of the method in C

```
rb_hash_select(VALUE hash)
{
    VALUE result;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(hash, 0, 0, hash_enum_size);
    result = rb_hash_new();
    if (!RHASH_EMPTY_P(hash)) {
        rb_hash_foreach(hash, select_i, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-select

Comment: I have provided a block, it still returns an enumerator

Comment: Then it probably wasn't the select method? But rather had to do with the p method?

Comment: It seems like that from other answer