# What is this syntax called? { |n| "user#{n}" }

Tags: ruby, syntax

```
{ |n| "user#{n}" }
```

The curly braces with two pipes. This is a ridiculous question, I know, but trying to google what the name of this syntax is has proven to be impossible.

Comment: There are those who call the two pipes, `|x|`, "goal posts"...

Comment: You'll often see them being called "closures". The language itself seems to call them blocks, there's the `block_given?` method for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s called a block. There are two types of blocks in ruby. One is this syntax in curly braces and second is the `do end`. These both are interchangeable but the curly braces have higher precedence. Therefore these programs are interchangeable:

```
my_array.each do |element|
  puts element
end


my_array.each {|element|
  puts element
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5587264/2267838) discusses in good detail the difference between the two and when they aren’t interchangeable.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  This might explain your query regarding curly braces having higher precedence. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5587403/2267838

Comment: I will update my answer regarding procs being blocks. You’re right about that.

Comment: Thank you for the link regarding precedence. That's interesting. I was not aware of that.

Comment: See the difference between the two in `irb` or `pry`: `def x(arg = nil); puts block_given?; end`, `x x { }` and `x x do; end` (results are printed "inside out", e. g. the call on the right, then the call on the left)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this example @D-side. Its really helpful.

Comment: These two are NOT equal , one returns array and another one returns enumerator.

Comment: @Rajagopalan. You're right. But the examples I gave, they are interchangeable. They definitely are not equal.

Comment: @UsamaMan ALL RIGHT, okay

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be called a ["code block"](https://medium.com/@sihui/what-the-heck-are-code-blocks-procs-lambdas-and-closures-in-ruby-2b0737f08e95).

It seems to essentially be an anonymous function. `n` is the parameter of the function in this case.

Comment: cool, that link is exactly what I needed! I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes or whatever. :)

Comment: blue, why the rush to select an answer? Quick selections may discourage other answers and short-circuit others working on answers. There's no rush.

Comment: I mean, because the question is answered?

Comment: I don't see a problem with rushing to accept an answer. I  believe this shouldn't steer other people off writing better answers. @blue totally can change his mind about what answer to accept after the fact.