# Ruby curly bracket block syntax is not working while do...end works

Tags: ruby, whenever

I am using [this gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). When I use the following syntax, it works fine:

```
every :day do
  rake 'billing:daily'
end
```

However, when I use the following syntax, the gem is giving me syntax error:

```
every :day { rake 'billing:daily' }
```

Output:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:25:in `instance_eval': config/schedule.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
every :day { rake 'billing:daily' }
            ^
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever.rb:12:in `new'
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever.rb:12:in `cron'
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:42:in `run'
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:6:in `execute'
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/bin/whenever:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/whenever:23:in `load'
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/whenever:23:in `<main>'
```

Aren't both the same thing? Why is the former working but not the latter?

Comment: The documentation for [block argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) explains the difference between `{ ... }` and `do ... end`.

Comment: See also: [do..end vs curly braces for blocks in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5587264/421705)

Comment: You could go with `every :day, &->{ rake 'billing:daily'}` if you really wanted to :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a parsing/precedence issue. Braces try to bind to the nearest token, which is `:day` in this case, but you want it to bind to `every()`. You have to write `every(:day) { rake 'billing:daily' }` to explicitly bind it to the correct token.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby `2.4.2` [was introduced regression](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13898) in block parsing. While in ruby `2.4.1` you could use:

```rb
every :day { rake 'billing:daily' }
```

in ruby `2.4.2` you have to wrap the function parameters in brackets if you call it with a block otherwise you will get a `SyntaxError`:

```rb
every(:day) { rake 'billing:daily' }
```