# Unexpected output when using `select`

Tags: ruby

I'm going through a tutorial on Ruby that explains the neat construction the `select` method provides. As per that, the three print statements in the following code (filtering out even numbers) should produce an identical output:

```rb
numbers = (1..20).to_a
p numbers.select(&:even?)
p numbers.select { |x| x.even? }
p numbers.select do |x| x.even? end
```

When I run it, though, I get:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
#<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]:select>
```

Clearly, the third statement is off, even though it's impossible to tell why. It's just the curly braces replaced with the `do-end` block so it shouldn't change anything.

I'm on Ruby 2.5 so I guess either the tutorial was running some other version and something has changed? Or maybe there's some subtlety here that I'm not able to put my finger on.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587264/do-end-vs-curly-braces-for-blocks-in-ruby

Comment: @ellitt Thanks but I don't see a discussion there about why the return types are different. The accepted answer shows that difference in the output, but no one seems bothered by it! :D

Comment: You'll have to expand the comments on the accepted answer to see that discussion. Also  Ursus put it very nicely in the answer below.

Comment: @ellitt Ohh. I actually went crazy trying to scan through the stylistic discussion there and gave up. Yes, I saw the answer. Thanks to you too!

Comment: Asked a couple of times: [Ruby Block Syntax Error](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6854283/2988), [Code block passed to `each` works with brackets but not with `do`-`end` (ruby)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6718340/2988), [Block definition - difference between braces and `do`-`end` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6179442/2988), [Ruby multiline block without `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3680097/2988), [Using `do` block vs brackets `{}`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2122380/2988), [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/533008/2988), …

Comment: … [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/420147/2988), [Why aren't `do`/`end` and `{}` always equivalent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7487664/2988), [Wierd imperfection in Ruby blocks](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7620804/2988), [Passing block into a method - Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/10909496/2988), [`instance_eval` block not supplied?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/12175788/2988), [block syntax difference causes “`LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)`”](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/18623447/2988), …

Comment: … [`instance_eval` does not work with `do`/`end` block, only with `{}`-blocks](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/21042867/2988), [`Proc` throws error when used with `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/25217274/2988), [Block not called in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/29454056/2988), and [Different behaviour of “`do … end`” and “`{ … }`” block in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/37638152/2988).

Comment: @JörgWMittag The problem is, it's hard to guess the working that was used to ask similar or exactly same questions. Anyway, thanks for your inputs! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p numbers.select do |x| x.even? end
```

is called in this way

```
p(numbers.select) do |x| x.even? end
```

The block is passed to `p`, not to `select` as you'd expect, `p` just ignores it

In the second case this doesn't happen because the block with {} has higher precedence than the method call. Instead, block with do-end has lower precedence than the method call.

The second case looks like this instead

```
p(numbers.select { |x| x.even? })
```

Comment: Amazing. Mind-blowing and mind-smashing at the same time! :D I think the use of `p` was somewhat of a contrived example because we'd almost always collect these values in a variable first; but it's always good to know. Thanks!