# differing `puts` behavior inside `do..end` blocks and curly braces in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm an experienced developer but a Ruby newbie.  I was reading this thread [do..end vs curly braces for blocks in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587264/do-end-vs-curly-braces-for-blocks-in-ruby) and learned some good stuff about when to use braces and when to use `do .. end` blocks.  One of the tips was use `do .. end` when you are after side effects and {} when you are concerned about the return value. So experimenting with some of the examples in the enumerator tutorial I'm going through:

```
irb(main):001:0> my_array = [1, 2]
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):002:0> my_array.each {|num| num *= 2; puts "The new number is #{num}."}
The new number is 2.
The new number is 4.
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):003:0> my_array.each do |num| num *= 2; puts "The new number is #{num}." end
The new number is 2.
The new number is 4.
=> [1, 2]
```

Hang on.  I thought the `do..end` block returns an enumerator object?  It looks like an array.  Let's check:

```
irb(main):004:0> puts my_array.each {|num| num *= 2; puts "The new number is #{num}."}
The new number is 2.
The new number is 4.
1
2
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> puts my_array.each do |num| num *= 2; puts "The new number is #{num}." end
#<Enumerator:0x000055967e53ac40>
=> nil
```

Okay, it is an enumerator. But what happened to the output of the `puts` call in the loop on line 005? The {} had the expected side effect but not the `do..end` block, which seems to violate that rule of thumb.

What happened to my `"The new number is #{num}."` strings?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5587399/2988) answer your question?

Comment: It explains the first part, which I probably should have left out of my question as I think I get that. But I'm more concerned with where the output of `puts "The new number is #{num}."` goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do...end` and `{}` are 100% semantically equivalent for method blocks. Their only difference is their parsing precedence, so they evaluate differently

To really understand that difference, a few things first.

**Ruby lets you call methods without parens:**

```rb
my_object.my_method my_arg

# so my_arg could actually be a method! Let's put parens in to show that:
my_object.my_method(my_arg())
```

**Blocks in Ruby are method arguments** -- a syntax for passing in closures (except for the special keywords that act in the parent scope). The below two chunks are equivalent:

```rb
[1, 2, 3].map { |x| 2 * x }

# split out into two lines
double = ->(x) { 2 * x }  # shorthand for `lambda { |x| 2 * x }`
[1, 2, 3].map(&double)
```

Okay, so knowing all that, let's expose the difference between `{}` and `do...end`:

```rb
my_method [1, 2, 3].map { |x| 2 * x }

my_method([1, 2, 3].map { |x| 2 * x }) # parses like this


my_method [1, 2, 3].map do |x| 2 * x end

my_method([1, 2, 3].map) do |x| 2 * x end # parses like this

my_method([1, 2, 3].map) { |x| 2 * x }    # in other words
```

`{}` has more precedence than `do...end`, immediately getting associated to the method immediately to its left. `do...end` has lower precedence, and will associate with `my_method`, which gets passed `[1, 2, 3].map` and the block as arguments.

This means, what you did above is:

```rb
puts(my_array.each) { |num| num *= 2; puts "The new number is #{num}." }
```

You've passed into `puts` the `my_array.each`, which is an enumerator, and a block, and `puts` does nothing with the blocks passed into it, as do all methods by default.

Comment: Thanks for that, so well laid out and clear. I come from the world of Common Lisp so I can tell you I'm really pleased to learn Ruby has lambdas. I look forward to understanding this last point about methods ignoring by default block arguments as I work through all the tutorials that are on my plate ATM. Cheers.

Comment: @coby101: There's no difference to Common Lisp there. If you pass a lambda to a function but that function never calls the lambda, then nothing happens. `puts` has no use for a block, so it will never call it.

Comment: @coby101 you may enjoy this article: http://www.randomhacks.net/2005/12/03/why-ruby-is-an-acceptable-lisp/

Comment: Thanks, @Kache. It was an illuminating read and I almost got sucked into reading all the comments before I saw how long and dense they were!  Many of the same issues and points of view I recall well from my days in comp.lang.lisp.  Written 15 years ago, I get the impression that Ruby has grown and aged well.