# block syntax difference causes "LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)"

Tags: ruby, block

Saw a strange case come up, trying to figure out what is happening here:

```
> def test
>   p yield
> end
=> nil
> test { 1 }
1
=> 1
> p test { 1 }
1
1
=> 1
> p test do
>   1
> end
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
```

Comment: Here is the answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533008/what-is-the-difference-or-value-of-these-block-coding-styles-in-ruby/533040#533040

Comment: here is the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122380/using-do-block-vs-brackets?lq=1

Comment: This is why you use parentheses, even though Ruby lets you choose.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The parser recognizes this

```
p test do
  1
end
```

as this

```
p(test) do
  1
end
```

The block is passed to `p`, not `test`. Therefore, `yield` can't yield and raises that error.

Answer (score 17):

`do` and `{}` to denote blocks attached to methods are not completely interchangeable.

```
p test do
  1
end
```

Precedence is screwing with you.  This is actually this:

```
p(test()) do
  1
end
```

So the block is getting passed to `p`, not `test`.

`{}` has higher precedence than `do`, and so binds more tightly to the syntactically closer method.  This is also true for other ruby keywords that have symbolic equivalents, such as `and`/`&&` and `or`/`||`, which is why the symbols are usually recommended over the words.