# Why does my recursive function not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j.rb

I have a rails model (Comment) which is based on neo4j.rb. My simple method should return the number of children, but is instead returning a LocalJumpError (no block given (yield)). What am I doing wrong?

```
has_many :both, :children, model_class: Comment, unique: true

def get_number_of_replies
    if children.count == 0
      0
    else
      children.count + children.each.get_number_of_replies
    end
end
```

Comment: I suspect you need some parentheses.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623447/block-syntax-difference-causes-localjumperror-no-block-given-yield

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
children.count + children.each.get_number_of_replies
```

should be

```
children.count + children.collect(&:get_number_of_replies).sum
```

As your error indicates, `each` expects a block.

Comment: This returns a SystemStackError(stack level too deep), but is definitely the right way to go.
EDIT: I have only one nested comment, so the error can not be that I have too many comments.

Comment: And children.children.count returns 0

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through every children to get the result you want:

```
def get_number_of_replies
  if children.count == 0
    0
  else
    total = 0
    children.each do |c|
      total += children.get_number_of_replies
    end
    children.count + total
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What Brad Werth wrote is correct. The problem was also that as children connections work both ways, I was creating an infinite loop. So here is the solution:

```
  has_many :out, :children, model_class: Comment, unique: true
  has_one :in, :child_of, model_class: Comment, unique: true

  def get_number_of_replies
    result = 0
    unless children.count() == 0
      result += children.count
      children.each do |child|
        result += child.get_number_of_replies
      end
    end
    result
  end
```